# Nothing showing on locahost for javascript files

Tags: javascript, html

I have two javascript files that should be drawing a canvas, but nothing is showing on the browser. Does anyone have any idea why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="sketch.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

sketch.js:

```
function setup() {
createCanvas(600, 600);
}

function draw() {
background(0);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you calling the `setup()` or `draw()` functions?  This code just looks like it declares these functions, but then never calls them.

Comment: ...and if you did call `setup()` or `draw()` you'd then get an error because they in turn call other functions that are not defined.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
window.onload = function() {
  setup();
  draw();
};
```

in your js file! so when the window loads, it executes the function automatically.

More info :
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Answer (score -1):

you have to call those functions. You are declaring them, but not using them

Do something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="sketch.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change()"/>
</head>
</html>
```

and then in the sketch.js write

```
function setup() {
createCanvas(600, 600);
}

function draw() {
background(0);
}

function change(){
setup()
draw()
}
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: So there is no way to make the canvas show automatically, without the user having to tell it to?

Comment: It can be called automatically on `DOM Load` event and I reckon you delete this post as you've multiple answers for this question.